# Div gets cloned multiple times instead of the required amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, methods, clone

I have some [JSON data that contains four sections](https://jsfiddle.net/y7b6cerd/), and I want my html div to be cloned depending on how many sections there are. So if I have 100 sections in my JSON, the div should be cloned 100 times.

My div is getting cloned and the JSON data is getting appended to each one, but **the problem is that the divs are getting cloned more than once.** The first JSON section gets cloned 4x, the second one 3x, the third one 2x, etc. There's a pattern here but I'm not sure why it's happening.

#### [JSON](https://jsfiddle.net/y7b6cerd/)

#### JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jsonData from "./test.json";

let onlyTitles = jsonData.d.results.filter(result => result.Title !== "");

onlyTitles.forEach(title => {
  let $clonedDiv = $("#template").clone();
  $clonedDiv.removeAttr("id");

  $clonedDiv.find("#filledRowBody").append(`<td>${title.Title}</td><td>${title.Role}</td><td>${title.Office}</td><td>${title.IsActive}</td>`);
  $clonedDiv.find("#filledRowBody").removeAttr("id");
  $("#titleBody").append($clonedDiv);
})
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="template" class="col-6">

  <h3 id="display-form-job-title"></h3>

  <div class="button-group">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Edit Form</button>

    <!-- Button trigger PDF -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="pdf-trigger" data-toggle="" data-target="#pdfprint">Save as PDF</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h4>Hiring Goals:</h4>

  <div class="col-12">
    <table class="table order-list" id="hiring-goals-table">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Number of Hires</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody class="tbody-hire">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <h4>Open Searches:</h4>

  <div class="col-12">
    <table class="table order-list" id="role-table">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Role</td>
          <td>Location</td>
          <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody class="tbody-search">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <h4>Roles Filled:</h4>
  <div class="col-12">
    <table class="table order-list" id="role-table">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td class="thead-emp">Name</td>
          <td class="thead-role-fill">Role</td>
          <td class="thead-loc-fill">Location</td>
          <td class="thead-act-fill">Active</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr id="filledRowBody">

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="titleBody">

</div> <!-- col-6 -->
```

Comment: You sure the code shown isn't inside another loop? You have some repeating ID issues but I don't see why what you have shown would create such duplications

Comment: Create a runnable demo that reproduces problem

Comment: Hey @charlietfl based on your comment I wondered if the problem was somewhere in the HTML, and sure enough `#titleBody` was _inside_ of `col-6 div` which led to the duplications. But thanks for looking over my code!

Comment: Still don't understand how that would cause duplications but if it solved problem...great!

Comment: Neither do I! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `#titleBody` was inside of the `col-6 div` which somehow led to the duplications.